# shell script with SFTP from PHP

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell

I have a shell script in Linux that performs SFTP to get some files. It works fine when I execute it from a terminal.

I am trying to call the script from PHP. It seems to work until the `echo`, and then it doesn't do anything.

The script and the PHP file are in the same folder.

This is the PHP code:

```
<?php 
$comando = "sh ftpgesdoc.sh";
$result=exec($comando);
echo $result; 
?>
```

And this is shell script. When I execute from the web, I can see the `echo "ejecutando sftp"`, but nothing happens after this point.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "ejecutando sftp"
folder="/aaa/bbb"
file="xxx.PDF" 
sftp UserXX@nnn.nn.n.nn << EOF
cd $folder
get $file test.pdf
EOF
```

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10894554/redirect-output-of-command-with-heredoc/10894659#10894659

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32412839/including-some-sftp-commands-in-a-makefile

Answer (score 0):

[`exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) returns only the last line from the command output. If you want to capture entire output, use [`proc_open`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37072220/why-commands-with-ssh2-exec-do-not-end/37073326#37073326), for instance.

Answer (score 0):

you have to give the full path to file

and use this  **2>&1**  and know the error

try something like this

```
$comando = "sh pathTofile/location/ftpgesdoc.sh";

if(exec("$comando  2>&1", $output, $return_var))
{
    print_r($output);
    echo "<br>";
   print_r($return_var);

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried with the full path, but I have the same result- nothing happens after the echo.

Comment: I tried again, and I have more information about the error. It seems that I need some additional library. Thanks again. 

    => /usr/bin/ssh: /opt/lampp/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: version       `OPENSSL_1.0.1' not found (required by /usr/bin/ssh) [2] => Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer )